# Apache como redirecionar porta?

Tags: apache

Como eu redireciono meu site padrão do apache que está na porta 80 para um serviço web na porta 8080?

Utilizo CentOS 7

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) do módulo [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). 

No exemplo abaixo, tudo que chegar na porta 80 será redirecionado para a aplicação disponível em `http://localhost:8080/app`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName dominio.com.br
  ServerAlias dominio.com.br
  ProxyPass http://dominio.com.br http://localhost:8080/app
  ProxyPassReverse http://dominio.com.br http://localhost:8080/app
</VirtualHost>
```

Mais explicação na documentação [oficial](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

Answer (score -2):

Pra mim, só deu certo dá forma abaixo, aplicativo roda em docker é o hassio, usei dominio registrado, tenho site instalado no domínio sem prejudicar o funcionamento

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName hassio.exemplo.ong.br
ServerAlias www.hassio.exemplo.ong.br
ProxyPass /hassio http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /hassio http://localhost:8123/
</VirtualHost>
```